# Mongo return first set of results found from 3 finds()

Tags: mongodb, find

Is there a way for me to search a list of options until one of them comes back with results? Or is there a better way in general to find records with the following three queries:

```
{
    "geoTargets.countries.name": {$in: ["US"]},
    "geoTargets.countries.regions.name": {$in: ["NY", "NJ"]},
    "geoTargets.countries.regions.cities.name": {$in: ["City 1", "City 2", "City 3"]}
},
{
    "geoTargets.countries.name": {$in: ["US"]},
    "geoTargets.countries.regions.name": {$in: ["NY", "NJ"]}
},
{
    "geoTargets.countries.name": {$in: ["US"]}
}
```

I am trying to search and I want to do this:

1. First try to find results that match one of the cities
2. If nothing is found try to find results that match one of the regions
3. Again if nothing is found try to find results that match just on the coutries

In my application I am doing an if like search:

Take this slimmed down version of node (not real, just for purpose of visualization), This is the way that I am basically searching. It doesn't seem like it is the best that it could be. It seems like this would be slow. Is there a way in MongoDB to do this as one query?

```
var results = db.campaigns.find({
    "geoTargets.countries.name": {$in: ["US"]},
    "geoTargets.countries.regions.name": {$in: ["NY", "NJ"]},
    "geoTargets.countries.regions.cities.name": {$in: ["City 1", "City 2", "City 3"]}});

if(results.length == 0){
    results = db.campaigns.find({
        "geoTargets.countries.name": {$in: ["US"]},
        "geoTargets.countries.regions.name": {$in: ["NY", "NJ"]}});

    if(results.length == 0){
        results = db.campaigns.find({"geoTargets.countries.name": {$in: ["US"]}});
    }
}

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the [**$or**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/#behavior) operator to club these conditions together and execute them.

The Boolean `$or` operator of the aggregation framework does an `short circuit` evaluation, i.e, if the preceding condition is satisfied, the rest of the conditions are not executed against the document.

```
var condA = {
    "geoTargets.countries.name": {$in: ["US"]},
    "geoTargets.countries.regions.name": {$in: ["NY", "NJ"]},
    "geoTargets.countries.regions.cities.name": {$in: ["City 1", "City 2", "City 3"]}
};
var condB = {
    "geoTargets.countries.name": {$in: ["US"]},
    "geoTargets.countries.regions.name": {$in: ["NY", "NJ"]}
};
var condC = {
    "geoTargets.countries.name": {$in: ["US"]}
};
```

and execute it as:

```
db.campaigns.aggregate(
 [
  {$match:{$or:[condA,condB,condC]}}
 ],function(err,data){
      //callback
  })
```

> $or uses short-circuit logic: the operation stops evaluation after
>   encountering the first true expression.

Although this behavior of the `$or` operator is not documented when used as a query operator in a `find()` query, you could try it as well and see which one is more efficient for your data set.

Comment: awesome! I will give it a try!

Comment: @BathScream to use `find()` I had to remove the `$match`, because it gave me an error saying `BadValue unknown top level operator: $match'`, would this do the same thing? `{$or: [citySearch, regionSearch, countrySearch]}` The `find()` seems to run faster than the `aggregate()`

Comment: @TheBoogieMan - Yes. The `$match` operator is an aggregation pipeline operator and cannot be used with the `find()` query. The document explicitly doesn't mention that it is a short circuit operator, when used in a find() query. But logically it should work the same way. You could use which ever gives you a better response time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Logical Query Operators: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-logical/
To get a count of documents that match a query condition, include the $match stage as well:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
      { $match: <query condition> },
      { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
   ]
)
```

Docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/

Comment: I'm not looking for a count, I am looking for a list of documents, of those three that return data first, starting with the top one, if that doesn't return results try the next one, and if that doesn't try the third one.